# addSnapshotListener code compiles and works but getting error: Cannot convert value of type '()' to closure result type 'Title?'

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

The code compiles and works but throwing the error when viewing the code.

```
func subscribe() async {
        let uid = auth.currentUser.uid
        print("Library.subscribe() \(uid)")
        
        if listenerRegistration == nil {
            
            listenerRegistration = db.collection(collectionRootLib).document(uid).collection(collectionUserLib).addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
         
                guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                    print("No documents")
                    return
                }
                
                self.content = documents.compactMap { queryDocumentSnapshot in
                    try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: Title.self)  // <= cannot convert Error 
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The two errors thrown are:
Argument passed to call that takes no arguments
Cannot convert value of type '()' to closure result type 'Title?'

Putting the try into a do/catch block doesn't seem to be the correct fix.

Comment: Can you check this [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63968115/18265570)?

Answer (score 1):

Updated to Xcode-13.4.1 and no longer have these compiler errors showing when viewing Firebase codable extensions.